# Use each function with getJSON an internal file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a noob. Sorry for this. I have a json file and an index.html, want to display json data in the html. What am I missing? Thank you.

I have a json file

*myinfo.json* (validated)

```
[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}]
```

and this

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("myinfo.json", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                $("<li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "</li>").appendTo("#groups");
            });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your getJSON callback function should probably look like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVm7v/3/):

```
function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, record) {                
                    $("<li>" + record.firstName + " " + record.lastName + "</li>").appendTo("#groups");
            });
}
```

There is no need to iterate twice through the array.

Comment: If your server delivers the json file correctly, it will work. Is it sending it correctly, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: :) You are accessing your files directly from disk. For the getJSON to work, you should host them on a webserver. What OS are you using?

Comment: How did you set up the webserver, is it configured to deliver files with the json extension?

Comment: I forgot setting up JSON in ASP.NET config file. you answer works :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different variable names, not only "data" in all iterations